# Graph algorithm library in Flutter, or python igraph integration for android apps

Tags: python, android, flutter, graph-theory, igraph

I recently started a personal project to make an app for myself to keep track of my workouts in gymnastics. I'm sure plenty of apps are out there already, but I'm doing it for my personal learning.

I am a Python developer and I don't have any experience with Android development. I have started checking Flutter out and think I'll go that way. However, one of the key features I'm thinking of would involve a directed graph of moves which in Python I would model with iGraph, and I don't think there's a Dart version. I'm not thinking about displaying the graph but having the internal representation and algorithm library.

I was wondering if someone could give me a bit of guidance on whether Flutter is the right choice, or how I can deal with having a Python "back-end" to my app so that I can process the data with Python, but still build the app for Android.

Thank you all :)

Comment: if you want to write in Python then maybe you should use [kivy](https://kivy.org/) or [flet](https://flet.dev/) or [beeware](https://beeware.org/)